# Pass Google Apps Script variable to HTML script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I have a trigger set up in Google Sheets so a URL is automatically opened in a new browser window. This works if the URL is hardcoded. I want the URL to be a variable. How do I pass the URL variable from Apps Script to HTML script? I'm a novice coder so please explain like I'm 5.

This function works if the URL is text like 'https://www.google.com'

```
function openMap() {
  var maplink = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B2").getValues();
  var js = "<script>window.open('https://www.google.com', '_blank', 'width=800, height=600');google.script.host.close();</script>";
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(js)
    .setHeight(10)
    .setWidth(100);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Now loading.'); 
}
```

This function does not if the URL is a variable (I checked the maplink value and its a valid URL)

```
function openMap() {
  var maplink = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B2").getValues();
  var js = "<script>window.open('maplink', '_blank', 'width=800, height=600');google.script.host.close();</script>";
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(js)
    .setHeight(10)
    .setWidth(100);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Now loading.'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join strings in the following manner:

```
...
var url = 'https://www.google.com';
var js = "<script>window.open('" + url + "', '_blank', 'width=800, height=600');google.script.host.close();</script>";
...
```

Basically

- you close the first part of your hardcoded string by closing the quotes
- add the dynamical variabl with `+`
- continue the hardcoded string by appending the second part with `+` and opening the quotes again

I hope this is clear!

Comment: So simple! Thank you. This works: var js = "<script>window.open('" + maplink + "',...